# If $\,\,f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}, \,b-a\ge 4$, is differentiable, then $\,f'(x_0)<1+(\,f(x_0))^2$, for some $x_0\in (a,b)$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, functional-inequalities

Suppose that $\,f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$, where $\,b-a\ge 4,\,$ is differentiable in $(a,b)$ and continuous in $[a,b]$. Prove that there is $x_0\in (a,b)$, such that

$$f'(x_0)<1+\big(\,f(x_0)\big)^2\!.$$

But, I could not make the slightest approach towards the solution of this problem. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Is it continuous at $a$ and $b$?

Comment: $f$ is continous at $a$ and $b$. Yes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**First proof.** (Assuming that $\,f$ is continuously differentiable). Assume that for every $x\in[a,b]$:
$$
f'(x)\ge 1+f^2(x),
$$
then
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\tan^{-1}\big(f(x)\big)=\frac{f'(x)}{1+f^2(x)}\ge 1,
$$
and thus integrating in $[a,b]$
$$
\tan^{-1}\big(f(b)\big)-\tan^{-1}\big(f(a)\big)\ge b-a\ge 4.
$$
But $\tan^{-1}(x)\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, and hence
$$
\tan^{-1}\big(f(b)\big)-\tan^{-1}\big(f(a)\big)<\pi.
$$

**Alternative proof.** (Assuming that $f$ is ONLY differentiable). As $\tan^{-1}: \mathbb R\to (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, then, using the mean value theorem for $g(x)=\tan^{-1}\big(f(x)\big)$, with $g'(x)=f'(x)/\big(1+f^2(x)\big)$, we obtain that there exists a $\xi\in (a,b)$, such that 
$$
\pi>\tan^{-1}\big(f(b)\big)-\tan^{-1}\big(\,f(a)\big)= (b-a)\frac{f'(\xi)}{1+f^2(\xi)},
$$
and hence
$$
1+f^2(\xi)>\frac{\pi}{b-a}\big(1+f^2(\xi)\big)= f'(\xi).
$$

Comment: Wow... I didn't see that at all...

Comment: Well, that's very advanced and nice stuff...thank you.